# Get current value of global variable on resize

Tags: jquery

My current project requires certain variables be reused in multiple separate functions.

Is it possible to get updated values of global variables at the time an event is triggered?

```
var $container          = $('.ub-slider-container');
var $container_width    = $container.width();

function slide_size() {
    var $header             = $('table tbody th');
    var $header_width       = $header.width();

    $('.slide').width($container_width - $header_width);
}

$(window).on('load resize orientationchange', function(){
    slide_size();
})
```

*Is this enough information or do you need more?*

Comment: Just replace `$('.slide').width($container_width - $header_width);` with `$('.slide').width($('.ub-slider-container').width() - $header_width);` and it should work. The reason is that this way you ask for the width of the container **at the time of the event** instead of storing it once globally

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  Which global variable are you concerned about?  Does `$container.width()` ever change?

Comment: Thank you @nem! It sounds like it isn't possible to do this the way I was planning. Thanks for clearing that up!

Comment: @Mo_ No problem, glad to help  :)